# Dynamic Listview with multiple items

Tags: c#, listview, dynamically-generated

So, i have been working in a school project and i need to create and add things to a listview dynamically the 1st adds without any problem, but when it's about to add the 2nd one it crashes.

here is the code:

```
        lvwCarros.Columns.Clear();
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        int idx, idx2;
        lvwCarros.Columns.Add("Carro", 80, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvwCarros.Columns.Add("Ano", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvwCarros.Columns.Add("Stand", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvwCarros.Columns.Add("Localização do Stand", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        for (idx = 0; idx < Program.Carros.Count  ; idx++)
        {
            lvi.Text = Program.Carros[idx].Marca + " " + Program.Carros[idx].Modelo;

            for (idx2 = 0; idx2 < Program.Matriculas.Count  ; idx2++)
            {
                if (Program.Carros[idx].Matricula == Program.Matriculas[idx2].ID_Matricula)
                {
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(Program.Matriculas[idx2].Ano_Emissão.ToString());
                    for (int idx3 = 0; idx3 < Program.Stands.Count; idx3++)
                    {
                        if (Program.Carros[idx].Proprietario == Program.Stands[idx3].ID_Stand)
                        {
                            lvi.SubItems.Add(Program.Stands[idx3].Nome_Stand);
                            lvi.SubItems.Add(Program.Stands[idx3].Local_Stand);
                        }
                        lvwCarros.Items.Add(lvi);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        lvwCarros.Visible = true;
        lvwCarros.Enabled = true;
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: any exception when debugging?

Comment: Yes 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: It says i can't insert the 2nd item in more than one place... 1st i need to remove it from the current location or clone it.

Comment: can you upload a screen capture of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your problem is that your lvi needs to be a new object every time you call lvwCarros.Items.Add().  Try putting an "lvi = new ListViewItem(first subitem);" in there at the top of that innermost for loop.  You can only add each ListViewItem object to the ListView once--this is why you're getting your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the running code. There were two problems in this code:

1. Each List item to be added should be instantiated in the for loop as it will create a new item. Otherwise, you will be adding the same item again and again and modifying the value of all the items if one item is changed as they will point to same item. Hence move the line `ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();` in the for loop if you want to create different list view items.
2. You are adding the listview item `lvi` in the internal for loop which is causing it to add the each listitem multiple time. Thats why you are getting the error. Move this line in the outermost for loop and the error will go away.

   ```
   lvwCarros.Columns.Clear();

   int idx, idx2;
   lvwCarros.Columns.Add("Carro", 80, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
   lvwCarros.Columns.Add("Ano", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
   lvwCarros.Columns.Add("Stand", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
   lvwCarros.Columns.Add("Localização do Stand", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
   for (idx = 0; idx < Program.Carros.Count  ; idx++)
   {
      /* You should initiate a new item in the loop if you want to add more*/
      ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

       lvi.Text = Program.Carros[idx].Marca + " " + Program.Carros[idx].Modelo;

       for (idx2 = 0; idx2 < Program.Matriculas.Count  ; idx2++)
       {
           if (Program.Carros[idx].Matricula == Program.Matriculas[idx2].ID_Matricula)
           {
               lvi.SubItems.Add(Program.Matriculas[idx2].Ano_Emissão.ToString());
               for (int idx3 = 0; idx3 < Program.Stands.Count; idx3++)
               {
                   if (Program.Carros[idx].Proprietario == Program.Stands[idx3].ID_Stand)
                   {
                       lvi.SubItems.Add(Program.Stands[idx3].Nome_Stand);
                       lvi.SubItems.Add(Program.Stands[idx3].Local_Stand);
                   }

               }
           } 
       }
       /*Moving it to outermost for loop*/
       lvwCarros.Items.Add(lvi);
   }

   lvwCarros.Visible = true;
   lvwCarros.Enabled = true;
   ```